# Using multiple videos causing one video not to show up. Possible bootstrap grid issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I'm placing videos on my site and ran into a problem when placing the second one, which is in another .row In my example you can't see the videos and I'm not sure how to link it to a video that you can see without changing the video tags. I think something that may also be causing a problem is my fill that I have over both videos which overlays a color on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/fyq3hxvx/

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="http://codepen.io/ArnaudBalland/pen/ogoMvd">
      <div class="vidfill">
      </div>
      <video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop class="login">
        <source src="images/loginfade.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </a>
  </div>
```